# Scroll Position of a Div in Angular 7+

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div that scrolls internally.  I can't figure out why I'm not getting the 'scrollTop' position correctly.

```
 let box: any = document.querySelector('.scrollingBox');
 let currentPos = box.scrollTop;
 console.log(currentPos) // always is 0 despite scrolling in the div

<div class="scrollingBox">
    <ng-scrollbar #scrollRef class="scroller">
    <div class="container" style="position:relative">
        <div class="recentWrapper">
            <h4>New and Featured Releases</h4>
            <app-book [bookdata]="book" *ngFor="let book of featuredBooks"></app-book>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="libraryWrapper">
            <h4>The Library</h4>
            <app-book [bookdata]="book" *ngFor="let book of books"></app-book>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <a class="moreResults" [hidden]="!more" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="getMore()">&#9656;More results</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ng-scrollbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) instead

```
  @ViewChild('scrollingBox', {static: false}) scrollingBox: ElementRef;
 console.log(this.scrollingBox.nativeElement.offsetTop) //

<div class="scrollingBox" #scrollingBox>
    <ng-scrollbar #scrollRef class="scroller">
    <div class="container" style="position:relative">
        <div class="recentWrapper">
            <h4>New and Featured Releases</h4>
            <app-book [bookdata]="book" *ngFor="let book of featuredBooks"></app-book>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="libraryWrapper">
            <h4>The Library</h4>
            <app-book [bookdata]="book" *ngFor="let book of books"></app-book>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <a class="moreResults" [hidden]="!more" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="getMore()">&#9656;More results</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ng-scrollbar>
</div>
```

Comment: That gives me the offset from the top of the page, not the scroll position.  scrollTop doesn't work either

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz of your problem I cant answer just with assumptions and guessing thanks